# Verifying hashed password vs user input with crypt builtin

Tags: perl, crypt, sha512

I am trying to find out how to use Crypt function to verify stored hashed password with user's entered data.

I use below code to generate password's digest using randomly generated salt. In next step, I use previously generated digest to be used as salt for crypt function and user's input. Based on information in [this](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html) link, if the output of the crypt function is the same as our previously generated digest, then we are good to go.

The crypt function in `CheckThis` function, generates different output using previously generated digest, and this causes the problem. What am I not doing correctly?

Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub HashThis {
    # To generate random salt
    my @temp = (0..9, 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z');
    my $salt;
    $salt .= $temp[rand @temp] for 1..16;
    print "\nSalt is:\t\t",$salt,"\n";

    # makes digest for real password using salt
    my $digest = crypt(@_, '$6$'.$salt);

    return ($digest);
}

sub CheckThis {
    # compares if crypt return same digest as using digest as salt for userinput
    my $result;
    my ($ui, $digest) = @_;

    if (crypt($ui, $digest) eq $digest) {
        $result = "matching";
    } else {
        $result = "not matching";
    }    
    return ($result);
}

system "stty -echo";
print "\nReal password:\t\t ";
chomp(my $userpass = <STDIN>);
print "\n";
system "stty echo";

my $digest = HashThis($userpass);
print "\nDigest is:\t\t",$digest,"\n";

system "stty -echo";
print "\nTest password:\t\t ";
chomp(my $userinput = <STDIN>);
print "\n";
system "stty echo";

my $final_result = CheckThis($userinput, $digest);
print "\n",$final_result,"\n\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
my $digest = crypt(@_, '$6$'.$salt);
```

to:

```
my $digest = crypt($_[0], '$6$'.$salt);
```

My guess is that `crypt` expects to be passed 2 scalar values, and it evaluates the `@_` array variable in scalar context, which is 1 since you pass a single value to the `HashThis` `sub`.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable guess -- `perl -E 'say prototype("CORE::crypt")'` returns `$$`.